# Form Value with jQuery and POST - Single Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, checkbox

This successfully returns a result, but the result is useless to me. In the php file, I have this simple code: var_dump($_POST['rememberMe']);

Whether the checkbox is marked or not, the result is string(2) "on". How do I get a result that changes based on whether the checkbox is marked?

Thanks.

```
Remember Me: <input type="checkbox"
                    id="remember">

<div id="result" style="margin-top:20px;">


<script>

$("#submit").click(function(){
    submitLogin();
});

$("#password").keyup(function (f){
    if (f.keyCode == 13) {
        submitLogin();
    }
});


function submitLogin(){
    $.post("php/test.php", { 
        loginUsername:$('#username').val(), 
        loginPassword:$('#password').val(),
        rememberMe:$('#remember').val()
    }, function(data){
        $("#result").text(data);
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value attribute is mandatory for checkboxes and defaults to `on`. This applies whether the checkbox is checked or not, the value is always the same. What you want is to check the state of the checkbox (not its value).

```
$('#remember').prop("checked")
```

Btw, this is way faster than `.is(:checked)`, see http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/5 for a comparison.

Comment: .is(':checked') <-- Thanks.

Comment: `.prop()` is way faster, though.

Comment: I posted before you edited to add that. Thanks, I'll choose yours as the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you serialized the form that you are sending via post $("form").serialize(); Then, in the target page, just check if $_POST['rememberMe'] exists. (If the checkbox isn't checked, isset for $_POST['rememberMe'] will be equal to false)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
rememberMe:$('#remember').val()
```

Needed to become:

```
rememberMe:$('#remember').is(':checked')
```

Comment: `$("#expire")`? Where does that fit in to your code?

Comment: @winterblood Sorry, I edited the code for use and when I copy/pasted, I forgot to set it back. It's fixed. ;)